# How to redirect all the traffic to a domain in Azure using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I have 2 VM's. I can access the application gateway with the IP address after creating the application gateway. Now I want to redirect all the traffic to my specific domain using dns record. If I open the domain mydomain12.com it should show me the VM's.

The code I have

```
resource "random_string" "rg" {
  length  = 8
  upper   = false
  special = false
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "101-application-gateway-${random_string.rg.result}"
  location = "eastus"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "myVNet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  address_space       = ["10.21.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "frontend" {
  name                 = "myAGSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.21.0.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "backend" {
  name                 = "myBackendSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.21.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
  name                = "myAGPublicIPAddress"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}
resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "yourdomain12.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  zone_type           = "Public"
}

# Create a DNS A record for the Application Gateway
resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "example" {
  name                = "appgateway"  # Replace with your desired hostname
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = [azurerm_public_ip.pip.ip_address]
}


resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "main" {
  name                = "myAppGateway"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

  sku {
    name     = "Standard_v2"
    tier     = "Standard_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "my-gateway-ip-configuration"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.frontend.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = var.frontend_port_name
    port = 80
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = var.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pip.id
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = var.backend_address_pool_name
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = var.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 60
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = var.listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = var.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = var.frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Http"
    host_name                     = "yourdomain12.com"
  }
  redirect_configuration {
    name="redirectHttpToHttps"
    redirect_type = "Permanent"
    target_listener_name = var.listener_name
    target_url = "https://yourdomain12.com"
    include_path = true
    include_query_string = true
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = var.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = var.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = var.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = var.http_setting_name
    priority                   = 1
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  count               = 2
  name                = "nic-${count.index+1}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "nic-ipconfig-${count.index+1}"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.backend.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_application_gateway_backend_address_pool_association" "nic-assoc" {
  count                   = 2
  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.nic[count.index].id
  ip_configuration_name   = "nic-ipconfig-${count.index+1}"
  backend_address_pool_id = one(azurerm_application_gateway.main.backend_address_pool).id
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  length  = 16
  special = true
  lower   = true
  upper   = true
  numeric = true
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  count               = 2
  name                = "myVM${count.index+1}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  size                = "Standard_DS1_v2"
  admin_username      = "azureadmin"
  admin_password      = random_password.password.result

  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic[count.index].id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }


  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm-extensions" {
  count                = 2
  name                 = "vm${count.index+1}-ext"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm[count.index].id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server; powershell Add-Content -Path \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Default.htm\" -Value $($env:computername)"
    }
SETTINGS

}
```

If I go to my domain yourdomain12.com I still can't see the VM's. I am really stuck on how to proceed further. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to redirect all the traffic to a domain in Azure using Terraform I was able to provision the required configuration successfully.

It seems like you want to create an Azure Application Gateway and configure it to redirect traffic from your domain (yourdomain12.com) to two Azure virtual machines

Since no errors are mentioned in the query I tried with the code provided and to achieve the configuration you are looking for the necessary changes should be made in **`azurerm_network_interface_application_gateway_backend_address_pool_association`**

As the module was provided incorrect configuration to achieve the requirement mentioned I made the necessary changes in the code.

**My Terraform Configuration:**

```
resource "random_string" "rg" {
  length  = 8
  upper   = false
  special = false
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "101-application-gateway-${random_string.rg.result}"
  location = "eastus"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "myVNet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  address_space       = ["10.21.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "frontend" {
  name                 = "myAGSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.21.0.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "backend" {
  name                 = "myBackendSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.21.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
  name                = "myAGPublicIPAddress"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "yourdomain12.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "example" {
  name                = "appgateway"
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = [azurerm_public_ip.pip.ip_address]
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "main" {
  name                = "myAppGateway"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

  sku {
    name     = "Standard_v2"
    tier     = "Standard_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "my-gateway-ip-configuration"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.frontend.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = "frontend-port"
    port = 80
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "frontend-ip-config"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pip.id
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = "backend-pool"
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = "http-settings"
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 60
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = "http-listener"
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "frontend-ip-config"
    frontend_port_name             = "frontend-port"
    protocol                       = "Http"
    host_name                      = "yourdomain12.com"
  }
  
  backend_address_pool {
    name = "backend-pool"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = "routing-rule"
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = "http-listener"
    backend_address_pool_name  = "backend-pool"
    backend_http_settings_name = "http-settings"
    priority                   = 1
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  count               = 2
  name                = "nic-${count.index + 1}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "nic-ipconfig-${count.index + 1}"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.backend.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_application_gateway_backend_address_pool_association" "nic-assoc" {
  count                   = 2
 network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.nic[count.index].id
  ip_configuration_name   = "nic-ipconfig-${count.index + 1}"
 backend_address_pool_id = tolist(azurerm_application_gateway.main.backend_address_pool).0.id
}


resource "random_password" "password" {
  length  = 16
  special = true
  lower   = true
  upper   = true
  numeric = true
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  count               = 2
  name                = "myVM${count.index + 1}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  size                = "Standard_DS1_v2"
  admin_username      = "azureadmin"
  admin_password      = random_password.password.result

  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic[count.index].id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm-extensions" {
  count                = 2
  name                 = "vm${count.index + 1}-ext"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm[count.index].id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server; powershell Add-Content -Path \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Default.htm\" -Value $($env:computername)"
    }
SETTINGS
}

output "application_gateway_backend_address_pool_ids" {
  value = {
    for pool in azurerm_application_gateway.main.backend_address_pool :
    pool.name => pool.id
  }
}

output "virtual_machine_ids" {
  value = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm[*].id
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Application Gateway got created for me as well. But I cannot access the yourdomain12.com. I have the IP if the application gateway. If Give the IP address you will be able to access the page. Instead of the IP of application gateway I want the access the page with yourdomain12.com.

Comment: If the code is working fine. Try to check with the DNS record, Check the application gateway configuration and restart, and Check the backend pool, and Make sure that the backend pool for your application gateway is configured to route traffic to your virtual machines